# Visual Studio 2015 hybrid app - getting "EPERM, operation not permitted"

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app

I having kind of absurd situation and I will glad to hear how exactly you guys handling it:

I have a Hybrid App project, Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Tools. Inside it, under "res" folder I have app resources. The whole project, including resources, is under source control (TFS).

During build, resource files get copied into "..\platforms\android\res" folder.

First time, while the folder empty it succeeded - the files get copied as-is (e.g. read-only, since they are under source control). After that, during next build, it trying to overwrite these read-only files and failed, as expected - displaying that informative error: "EPERM, operation not permitted '*resource full path*'.

I don't get it. Resources must be under source control, so I guess 99.99% of developers would get the same problem as I do.

What do I miss?

Thanks

Comment: You can't just checkout the files?

Comment: @adelphus - it looks kind of weird to ask every developer in the (big) organization to check out specific files. What If I would like to update resources? Theoretically, I can prepare pre-build event to delete/remove read-only from existing files - but all of this look to me very dirty. I would like to know what is recommend best practice for this situation.

Comment: Surely TFS is not so retarded as to prevent developers committing files that others have checked out? I would say it's common practise for devs to checkout files in projects they are working on locally and just revert unchanged files when they're done.

Answer (score 14):

I thought I'd chime in here with what I've done. The problem is that "platforms" is not checked into source, but it is still being marked as Read-Only. So the first time it builds it works and subsequent builds fail unless you do a clean solution.

What I've done is I remove the Read-Only flag before build.

Right click project, Unload Project. Right click, edit project file. At the top, add a target named `BeforeBuild` for example:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="BeforeBuild;Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Then at the bottom of the file where the targets go you can add a target like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="attrib -R &quot;$(SolutionDir)YourProjectName\platforms\*.*&quot; /S" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with TFS but haven't had any luck.  Any ideas of how to follow the same pattern but for a TFS build?

Comment: This project builds on TFS build as well. We have our build template set up to completely clean (delete) the source directory before it grabs the latest source.

Comment: We are doing that too.  Sounds like I must have a different issue :(

Comment: Actually, we don't have that project building on TFS Build. It does build other projects in the solution. The reason it isn't building is because it is using the old version of TFS Build templates that didn't support NPM/Bower. It is just a test project anyway to see what Cordova can do.

You may be able to do something in a Gulp/Grunt file to change the permissions. If you are using the newer build templates then you can invoke Gulp/Grunt.

Comment: This worked for me and my workmate.
Should be the accepted answer

Comment: If you can't use a project build event then you could always write a Cordova after_prepare hook to do the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Check if the folder is Read Only, if it is - uncheck the "Read Only" property on the folder and select "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files"

I get the same exception when I use TFS with Cordova.

When I'm committing the folder become Read Only, that's a very annoying bug...

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get past this when building on TFS?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the directory that the error message pointed to was just plain missing.  Same IDE, same type of app.

It was looking for
\GitHub...\myProjectName\platforms\windows\www

I manually added the dir (www) back in and the project ran fine.  The IDE deletes that dir at the beginning of the build then throws the EPERM exception.  Sure looks like a bug to me.