# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open "C"

Tags: batch-file, tfs, build-definition

I am getting following error while running a build definition.

[image]

I tried to give read/write permission by right clicking the **Builds** directory, but after running the build using build definition the permissions get reset.

The files get created by calling "gulp" command from a **post script bat file**.
How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Not so familiar with gulp command . Did you need  to run `npm install`  in the script or in the build agent?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if it's related to the npm install issue. Please refer this [npm install fails on Windows with "EPERM, operation not permitted"](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/19)  for more details.

Here is also a similar question [Visual Studio 2015 hybrid app - getting "EPERM, operation not permitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924314/visual-studio-2015-hybrid-app-getting-eperm-operation-not-permitted)