# Gulp EPERM: operation not permitted using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, gulp, tfsbuild

I am trying to integrate our build server with our angular build.  Locally the build work perfectly but when I try and run the build on the build server I am getting the following error:

```
RunGulp:
Running gulp task dev
  gulp
  [08:35:38] Using gulpfile C:\Builds\10639\TCC.NET\1.Development CI\src\TCC.W
 eb.Client\gulpfile.js
 [08:35:38] Starting 'default'...
  [08:35:38] Starting 'build'...
  [08:35:38] Starting 'js'...
  stream.js:74
        throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^

EXEC : error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Builds\10639\TCC.NET\1.
 Development CI\src\TCC.Web.Client\public\app.module.js' [C:\Builds\10639\TCC.N
ET\1.Development CI\src\TCC.Web.Client\TCC.Web.Client.csproj]
      at Error(native)
C:\Builds\10639\TCC.NET\1.Development CI\src\TCC.Web.Client\TCC.Web.Client.wpp
.targets(14, 5): error MSB3073: The command "gulp" exited with code 1. [C:\Build
s\10639\TCC.NET\1.Development CI\src\TCC.Web.Client\TCC.Web.Client.csproj]
```

I've looked at some various posts on the error and they mostly revolve around permissions issues but the public folder and the app.module.js files have the correct permissions.

I am not at all familiar with gulp so looking for some other ideas on things to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue turned out to be the readonly flag on the files being built.

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925133/987685)